# Calling boolean values from different class

Tags: java, object, boolean

I have a main class where the object account has been defined. Then in another class I have written the following method:

```
public boolean withdraw(double withdrawAmt) {
    if (balanceAmount < withdrawAmt)
        return false;
        
    else{ 
        balanceAmount -= withdrawAmt;
            return true;
    }   
}
```

I have to define the following condition but I don't know how to access the boolean return from a different class.withdraw1 is int type and therefore it is producing an error.

This is what I have tried:

```
if (ac.withdraw(withdraw1)==false) {
    System.out.println("Insufficient balance");
    System.out.println("Available balance is:"+String.format("%.2f",ac.getBalanceAmount()));
} else if(ac.withdraw(withdraw1)==true) {
    System.out.println("Available balance is:"+String.format("%.2f",ac.getBalanceAmount()));
}
```

Comment: and ... what is the problem you are having?

Comment: You probably shouldn't be calling `withdraw` twice.

Comment: withdrawl1 is int type and therefore there is a clash.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you have done seems to be right.

Alternatively, you can directly use the value returned from withdraw method in if condition.

Also, no need to call withdraw method twice.

```
boolean withdrawn = ac.withdraw(withdraw1);
if (!withdrawn) {
    System.out.println("Insufficient balance");
    System.out.println("Available balance is:"+String.format("%.2f",ac.getBalanceAmount()));
} else {
    System.out.println("Available balance is:"+String.format("%.2f",ac.getBalanceAmount()));
}
```